# Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedItems' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

I fail when to trying select item from foreach().
My code like:

```
foreach (ListViewItem LISTA in this.lstImgAdded.SelectedItems)
{
    lstImgAdded.SelectedItems(i).Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of syntax error (you must use `[i]` instead of `(i)` for indexers), you don't need indexer here. Just use [`ListViewItem.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly on enumerated item:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lstImgAdded.SelectedItems)
{
    item.Remove();
}
```

Moreover, you should note two things:

- one can't use `ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection.Remove`, since it is [read-only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedlistviewitemcollection.isreadonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see "Remarks" section or [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,7441)):
- this is a that rare case, when it is safe to modify sequence, when iterating through it, because [`ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection.GetEnumerator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,7572) returns enumerator of a "snapshot" of selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Start counting from the end and continue until you reach zero.

```
for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems[i].Selected)
    {
        listView1.SelectedItems[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

If you have 10 items and delete the first, then the list only has 9 items left. As soon as you try to delete a missing item, in this case the 6th, you'll get an error.

Comment: You're iterating through all of items, instead of `SelectedItems` collection. What's the benefit?

Comment: Good spot. I haven't had coffee yet this morning!